# What is the correct term for unboarding passengers from aircraft?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am looking for a correct term meaning that the given plane is in a state of unloading/ "unboarding" arrived passengers, just before it will board departing passengers.

I can't find this on airport sites, and according to spellcheckers "unboarding" is not a correct word.

Comment: I thought you were talking about the incident on [United](https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/amp.news.com.au/travel/travel-updates/incidents/police-drag-bleeding-man-off-united-flight-in-the-us-because-he-refused-to-leave-overbooked-plane/news-story/0a6c60623ccc6fe56dfece6a8009bf8d) then I checked the date stamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[deboard](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deboard)*  (Wiktionary)

> To exit a form of transportation such as a boat, ship, airplane, trolley, streetcar or spaceship.

syn. *disembark*, *deplane*

Comment: Nice illustration of the limitations of synonymy.

Comment: [Debark](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/debark)?

Comment: If TV is right, it must be deplane: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USfKJYZcUmI

Comment: Standby passengers that can be kicked off by the airline if it needs the space for higher priority pax are known as "PAD" = passenger available for disembarkation :-)

Answer (score 5):

All my life I have heard ***deplane*** instead of ***deboard***. But it seems a difference without a distinction.

Comment: @fev It's a very common saying for this sort of thing, at least in my neck of the woods. Your comment comes off a bit snarky.

Comment: I agree, will delete it.

Comment: Yes, deplaning, OR disembarking, the older term.

Comment: Hello, Kevin. Can you add supporting reference? Or at least an estimate of frequencies. I don't think I've come across 'deplane' except in this thread. 'Disembark' I am familiar with (I last flew in 2017, and remember the Caravelle).

Comment: I used to hear disembarking, then in the past couple of decades, more of deplaning. But never deboarding.

Comment: *Deplane* seems to be a part of the jargon used by some airlines. Ordinary people may hear it in the announcements made by the flight attendants, but are unlikely to use it themselves; instead they would use *disembark* (which, of course, is not specific to planes), or just *get off the plane*.

Answer (score 0):

Alight - from most English dictionaries

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. You might want to *cite* a dictionary definition; this is not a common word (I never heard of it, but I'm not a native speaker so that doesn't count.)

Comment: ... It's not as common as it used to be, and formal, but is/was usually only used for getting off buses and trams.

Comment: This does not answer the question posed. *alight* describes what a single person does.  The questions asks about how to describe the plane’s state of unloading.